WinUI 3 (Windows App SDK) Globalized Exception Handling
In WinForms, we used the following in Main() or some other startup event:
System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadException += ExceptionHandler.Handle;

I searched for something similar in WinUI3 (Windows App SDK) and cannot seem to find anything.
Is there a globalized way of throwing up an exception notification for WinUI3?

Application.UnhandledException Event or Override Start WinUI 3.0 Desktop Application?

public App()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UnhandledException += App_UnhandledException;
}

private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the exception here.
}

According to some issues posted on the GitHub repo, for example this one, it doesn't catch all exceptions though.
